# Inherited IRA, cost basis and Form 8606

Tags: united-states, income-tax

It is my belief that Inherited IRAs have a separate cost basis then your IRA(s). That is, when you inherit an IRA from a non-spouse its cost basis is 0. As such, when filling out form 8606, line 6 you do not count the value of an inherited IRA.

Do I have my facts right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherited IRAs keep their original basis (assumed $0 by default, unless the decedent had a Form 8606 on file), and must be calculated on a separate 8606 from your IRAs (and inherited IRAs from different people), unless it's a spouse's IRA that you elect to treat as your own.

You wouldn't include the inherited IRA in the Form 8606 for your own IRA basis calculations. If the inherited IRA has its own basis, it needs its own 8606. If it has a $0 basis, no 8606 is needed.

[Pub 590b](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b)

> If you take distributions from both an inherited IRA and your IRA,
> and each has basis, you must complete separate Forms 8606 to determine
> the taxable and nontaxable portions of those distributions.